# How to create a simple dashboard from MySQL database using JavaScript & html

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, dashboard

I am retrieving the data from MySQL database to my console as a JSON format using JavaScript and I need to create a simple dashboard on that data 
can anyone help me?

Comment: Please be more specific. What data? What are DB tables? What is "my console"? If you use JS, where's the code you use? What's your problem with this?

Comment: Data are in integer format from MySQL DB, and my DB tables are timestamp, temp, humidity from dht 22 sensor. i m getting the DB output in my Linux terminal when i execute the js code. now how can i get them in HTML page or dashboard.